# __repr__ decorator fails on subclasses

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, subclassing

## Background

I wrote a decorator function to modify the `__repr__` of a given class, such that when an class instance is called all its attributes are printed to the user. When used in the on the `Container` class in the example below the decorator `__repr__dec` behaves as intended.

### Input

```
def __repr__wrapper(self):
    """Show all attributes."""
    return "Attributes: "+", ".join(list(self.__dict__.keys()))

def __repr__dec(func):
    """Replaces the __repr__ function of a class with __repr__wrapper"""
    def call(*args, **kwargs):
        func.__repr__ = __repr__wrapper
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return result
    return call


@__repr__dec
class Container(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.metadata = args[0]
        for k,v in kwargs.items():
            self.__dict__[k] = v

occ = Container(42, how="now")
occ
```

### Output

```
Attributes: metadata, how
```

However when trying to subclass `Container` I receive a TypeError message:

### Input

```
class Handle(Container):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Container.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

han = Handle(42)
```

### Output

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-b4c252411c1f> in <module>()
----> 1 class Handle(Container):
      2     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      3         Container.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
      4 
      5 han = Handle(42)

TypeError: function() argument 1 must be code, not str
```

## Question

Why does sub-classing `Conatainer` fail when using the `__repr__dec` function? Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: I didn't know that decorators don't get inherited. Now this is starting to make sense.

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel Metaclasses are overkill here. And "not inherited" is not an accurate description of what's happening. The decorated class object is _replaced_ with the `call` function defined in `__repr__dec`. In other words, `Container` is actually a function, not a class. _That's_ why trying to inherit from it throws an exception.

Comment: Why can't you just define `__repr__` in `Container`?

Comment: Your decorator is nothing but a function. You can't subclass functions.

Comment: Is it possible to make a decorator that returns a class instead of a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your decorator made `Container` a function and no longer a class. You can control it very simply:

```
>>> type(Container)
<class 'function'>
```

This is because your use of the decorator ends in the following:

- declare a undecorated class

  ```
  class Container:
      ...
  ```
- use the decorator on it:

  ```
  Container = __repr__dec(Container)
  ```

As `__repr__dec` returns a function you have indeed change `Container` into a function able to return objects having the expected `__repr__` member, but it is no longer a class.

Your decorator must return a class if you want to be able to later subclass it:

```
def repr_dec(cls):
    cls.__repr__ = __repr__wrapper
    return cls
```

Then everything is fine:

```
>>> Container
<class '__main__.Container'>
>>> occ=Container(42, how="now")
>>> occ
Attributes: metadata, how
```

And you can successfully subclass it:

```
>>> class Handle(Container):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Container.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

>>> han = Handle(42, foo="now")
>>> han
Attributes: metadata, foo
```

`Handle` class has inherited the `__repr__` method from its parent.

Answer (score 1):

```
def replace_str(cls):
    class Wrapper:
        def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
            self.wrapped = cls(*args, **kargs)
        def __getattr__(self, attrname):
            return getattr(self.wrapped, attrname)
        def __str__(self):
            return "Attributes: " + ", ".join(list(self.wrapped.__dict__.keys()))
    return Wrapper

@replace_str
class Container(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.metadata = args[0]
        for k,v in kwargs.items():
            self.__dict__[k] = v
```

Using a proxy class could easily achieve this.
also, `metaclass` could do this:

```
class PrintKey(type):
    def __new__(meta, classname, bases, namespace):
        namespace['__str__'] = lambda self: "Attributes: " + ", ".join(list(self.__dict__.keys()))
        return type.__new__(meta, classname, bases, namespace)

class Container(object, metaclass=PrintKey):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.metadata = args[0]
        for k,v in kwargs.items():
            self.__dict__[k] = v
```